# Клон в jquery

Tags: jquery

*Сразу попрошу помидорами не закидывать, т.к. сталкиваюсь с данным действом впервые*

Есть некая кнопка, по клику на которой нужно вставить новую строку в таблицу. Итак:

Есть таблица:

```
var elem = $(".content table");
```

Есть 4 ячейки:

```
var td1 = '<div class="folder_label">Название</div>';
var td2 = '<input type="text" name="label_name" value="Название"/>';
var td3 = elem.find("select:last-child").clone();
var td4 = '<button name="save">Сохранить</button><button name="del" >Удалить</button>';
```

Содержимое 3й ячейки я хочу скопировать с предыдущей строки (там select список), но только не так **`$("td").html();`** а именно обратившись к **select**. Т.е. в переменной td3 у нас сейчас объект, тот самый select.

Пытаюсь вставить:

```
elem.append("<tr><td>"+td1+"</td><td>"+td2+"</td><td>"+td3+"</td><td>"+td4+"</td></tr>");
```

Ну и естественно не получается, потому и пишу вопрос. =) Т.е. в 3-й ячейке у меня пишется **`[object Object]`**

Подскажите как правильно вставить этот объект? Или вообще, как правильней выполнить данную задачу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
elem.append("<tr><td>"+td1+"</td><td>"+td2+"</td><td></td><td>"+td4+"</td></tr>");
elem.find('tr:last td').eq(2).append(td3);
```

Примерно так. Потому что td3 - объект, и его надо вставлять append'ом.

Comment: Благодарю! Как всегда быстрый и правильный ответ!